# Fallout: New Vegas Audio Glitch

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

So I'm having this weird issue while playing Fallout: New Vegas.

At first, I thought I was unable to hear any kind of music or dialogues while playing the game but I just figured out that I can actually hear the dialogue from people by turning away in a direction not facing the person I'm talking to.

I'm unable to determine why this happens, it's not because of any mod, because I'm not using any.

A solution is much appreciated.

Comment: It should be something to do with how sound position is simulated. If you have 2.1 system, but enable 7.1 then probably weird things will happens. Try to rule out misconfiugration all the way: check system settings, try to play music, try another game, check fallout sound settings.

Comment: I'm not sure, but the same thing happened with Skyrim too

Comment: Skyrim is operating on a different game engine than Fallout. If you're having the same issue on different games then it probably isn't an issue with the games itself but your audio setup